# How to change submenu orientation (horizontal to vertical)

Tags: css, submenu

I have created a horizontal menu that has a horizontal submenu on one of the links. The people I am doing the site for now want the submenu to go vertically. I can not work out what CSS code I need to change in order to make the sub menu drop downwards from the parent link. The code is below for your perusal.

The website is [island-timber.com](http://island-timber.com/) on the products parent link.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Here's the amended CSS for the nav:

```
#top_nav    {

        width: 1050px;
        height: 66px;
        margin-left: 106px;
        z-index: 10;

}

#top_nav ul   {

        list-style: none;
        padding: 0px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 780px;
        position: relative;
        display: inline-table;

}

#top_nav li    {

        float: left;

}

#top_nav li a    {

        font: 20px Stencil;
        color: #FF0;
        font-weight: normal;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        width: 154px;
        height: 61px;
        line-height: 54px;

}

#top_nav li a:hover,  #top_nav li .active    {

        background: url(../images/active.png) center;

}

#top_nav li ul {

        display: none;
        position: absolute; 
        top: 100%; 
        width: 154px;

}

#top_nav li:hover > ul {

        display: block; /*block*/

}

#top_nav li ul li {

        float: none;
        position: relative;

}

#top_nav li ul a    {

        font: 12px Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
        padding-top: 12px;
        height: 30px;
        background-color: #FFF;
        color: #000;

}

And the amended CSS for the #prew_img tag:

#prew_img   {

        height: 297px;
        z-index: 5;

}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"       "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Island Timber &amp; Building Supplies | Home</title>
        <meta name="keywords" content="" />
        <meta name="description" content="" />
        <link href="stylesheets/itbm_styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="top_nav">
                  <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a></li>

        <li><a href="">Products</a>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="paintshop.html">Paintshop</a></li>
                <li><a href="timber.html">Timber</a></li>
                <li><a href="buildingins.html">Building Materials &amp; Insulation</a></li>
                <li><a href="adhesivesfix.html">Adhesives &amp; Fixings</a></li>
                <li><a href="toolscloth.html">Tools &amp; Clothing</a></li>
            </ul>

        </li>

        <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>

        <li><a href="offers.html">Offers</a></li>

        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul> 
    </div>
                                <div id="top_padding">          </div>

                                <div id="prew_img">

                   <ul class="round">
            <li><img src="images/paintshop_scroll_border.jpg" alt="Island Timber Johnstones paint shop" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/timberyard_scroll_border.jpg" alt="Island Timber Yard" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/shop_scroll_border.jpg" alt="Island Timber shop" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/wagon_scroll_border.jpg" alt="Island Timber delivery wagon" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/tools_scroll_border.jpg" alt="Island Timber tools section" /></li>
            <li><img src="images/adhesives_scroll_border.jpg" alt="Island Timber adhesives section" /></li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery.roundabout.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.round').roundabout();
            });

        </script>

        <div id="middle_padding"></div>
<div id="content_container">
    <div id="main_content">     
            <div id="overview"> 
                <h3>HOME</h3>
                <p>Established in 1998, Island &amp; Timber Building Materials Ltd, based in Ballasalla, Isle of Man, have been fulfilling the needs of both the professional trade and the keen DIYer ever since.  Our site carries a broad range of products which are in stock and available immediately for collection or delivery.</p><br />
                <p>We are members of the National Merchant Buying Society and have access to a wide range of suppliers so we can ensure we are providing excellent quality products at the best prices possible.</p><br />
                <p>We run a reliable delivery service and orders placed before 1:00pm are delivered next day. We offer cash on delivery and telephone payments for our non account customers and our fleet of specialist vehicles can cater for all delivery requirements.</p><br />
                <p>In our sawmill we have experienced staff to cut timber and sheet materials to your specifications.</p><br />
                <p>We pride ourselves on our excellent customer service, from enquiry through to delivery and our knowledgable team are always on hand to help and advise you, our valued customers.</p><br />
                <p>Please enjoy browsing our website, here you will see a fraction of the types of products we hold in stock, if you don't see what you are looking for please ask a member of the team, via our <a href="contact.html"> Contact page </a> or call us on 01624 827 338, and we will endeavour to source the product at the best price possible for you.</p>
            </div>
        </div>  
            <div id="right_col">    
            <div id="suppliers">    
            <h3>Some of our suppliers</h3>
            <div class="supplier_pic_line"> 
                <img src="images/everbuild_logo.jpg" alt="Ever Build logo" />
                <img src="images/faithfull_logo.jpg" alt="Faithfull Tools logo" />
            </div>
            <div class="supplier_pic_line"> 
                <img src="images/knauf_insulation_logo.jpg" alt="Knauf Insulation logo" />
                <img src="images/marshalltown_logo.jpg" alt="Marshalltown logo" />
            </div>  
            <div class="supplier_pic_line"> 
            <img src="images/johnstones_logo.jpg" alt="Johnstones Paints logo" />
            <img src="images/olympic_fixings_logo.jpg" alt="Olympic Fixings logo"  />
            </div>  
            <div class="supplier_pic_line"> 
            <img src="images/stanley_logo.jpg" alt="Stanley Tools logo" />
            <img src="images/irwin_logo.jpg" alt="Irwin Tools logo" />
            </div>  
            </div>  
            <div id="opening_times">
            <h3>Opening Times</h3>
            <p class="opening_times">Mon - Thurs - 7:30am to 5:00pm</p>
            <p class="opening_times">Friday - 7:30am to 4:30pm</p>
            <p class="opening_times">Saturday - 7:30am to 12:00pm</p>
            <p class="opening_times">Sunday - Closed</p>
            <br />
            <p class="opening_times">Tel: (01624) 827338</p>
            </div>  
            </div>
            </div>



    </div>          


</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141513/how-to-create-a-css-only-vertical-drop-down-menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this:

```
#top_nav li ul {

    position: absolute; top: 100%;;
}
```

into this:

```
#top_nav li ul {

    position: absolute; top: 100%; width:200px;
}
```

that should fix your problem
cheers, marco

---

Edit

---

```
#top_nav    {
          width: 1050px;
          height: 66px;
          margin-left: 106px;
}
#top_nav ul   {
        padding-left: 0px;
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 780px;
        position: relative;
        display: inline-table;
            z-index: 1010;
}
#top_nav ul li    { 
        float: left;
}
#top_nav ul li a    { 
        font: 20px Stencil;
        color: #FF0;
        font-weight: normal;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        width: 154px;
        height: 61px;
        line-height: 54px;
}
 #top_nav ul li a:hover,  #top_nav li .active    {
        background: url(../images/active.png) center;
}
#top_nav ul li ul {
        display: none;
        position: absolute; top: 100%; width: 200px;
}
#top_nav ul li:hover > ul {
        display: block; /*block*/
}
#top_nav ul li ul li {
        float: none;
        position: relative;
        background-color:red !important;
}
#top_nav ul li ul li a:active{
            background: url(images/active.png) center;
}
#top_nav ul li ul li a:hover{
            background-color:red;
}
#top_nav ul li ul a {
        font: 12px Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
        padding-top: 12px;
        height: 30px;
            background-color: #FFF;
        color: #000;
}
```

Comment: That's great thanks Marco, sorted the problem, how ever, the sub menu now goes behind the picture roundabout!  Is there CSS I can add to bring the sub menu to the front of the roundabout?  They also want the sub menu links to be within a white box, do I just need to add the relevant CSS to the #top_nav li ul a tag? many thanks, Phil

Comment: for the problem for it to fall behind the image you can use z-index.
z-index:10; for example. for the whitebox you can simply use background and then make it all dandy with css.

Comment: Cheers Marco, sorted the problem with it going behind the roundabout, had to use loads of padding when it was horizontal so just removed most of the padding and added a height tag.  I have added the white background but it disappears on mouse over, I have amended the CSS and added it below and uploaded the changes to the server so you can see the problem!!  Thanks for your help so far.  Phil

Comment: #top_nav li ul a {
 
  font: 12px Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  padding-top: 12px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  color: #000;

}

Comment: you'll probably want to remove the padding-top: 15px; from the ul:hover but that is personal opinion

Comment: Tried the z-index tag just out of curiosity, tried vlaue of 10 and 20, made the height of the sub menu items bigger so it goes behind the roundabout and it didn't make any difference, just thinking if they need more links later I should really do it like this, do I need to just keep changing the value until it comes to the front?  cheers again, Phil

Comment: The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element.
An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order. So if you give the menu a z-index of 2 and the image a z-index of 1 the menu should appear above the image. The reason i gave you z-index 10 is because if you ever want something else to appear above you image and menu you dont have to change the items.

Comment: Ah right, so I need to add a z-index tag to the roundabout as well?  I am also a little confused, the CSS that you have edited above doesn't look like mine, shall I amend to match your edited code?  Sorry but it has been a while since I coded!  Cheers, Phil

Comment: I suggest that every time you have 2 or multiple items overlapping each other that you use z-index. The css is still yours but i cleaned it up a little bit. The only things i changed / added were the width of the ul and the ul:hover part.

Comment: Could you also mark my answer as approved if you agree that i solved you problem? This is simply that other users know that this solved it.

Comment: Great stuff, thanks Marco, I will amend the CSS and add the z-index tag to the roundabout, could you advise which part of the roundabout I need to add the z-index tag to?  I will add the roundabout CSS below.  Thanks once again, Phil

Comment: .roundabout-holder {
  
  list-style: none;
  width: 50em;
  height: 10em;
  margin: 1em auto;

}
   
.roundabout-moveable-item {
    
  height: 300px;
  width: 562px;
  cursor: pointer;

}
   
   
.roundabout-moveable-item img {
    
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

}
   
.roundabout-in-focus { 

  cursor: auto;
  
}

Comment: you can simply give the z-index to the id of the slider which is : prew_img. So the code would be. #prew_img{ z-index:5; } This automatically makes everything with a higher z-index go over its content.

Comment: Great stuff, I will get on it now.  Is the lower the z-index value the lower in the hierarchy it is?  So if I set prew_img as 1, this will be right at the back and anything above this will be overlapping in front, relatively, so 1 is at the back, 2 in front of 1, 3 infront of 2 etc? Yep will mark as answered.  One thing I am a little confused with though is your amended CSS, you have added the tag #top_nav li ul:hover and its relevant values, but further up you say to remove the padding-top value in order for the white background to stay on mouseover, could you confirm this?  Many thanks, Phil

Comment: Tried the z-index, set prew_img to 5 and #top_nav to 10, made the sub menu height larger so it goes behind the roundabout and it hasn't made any difference, any idea's?  Cheers, Phil

Comment: yes, the padding-top just creates an ugly empty space at the top of the menu items so its best to just remove it. and you got z-index correct. the higher the number the more on top the item is. I will look into you line-height problem can you edit your original post with your current code? html and css.

Comment: I updated the CSS code.  I think we may have got our wires crossed about the white background on the sub menu, when I mouse over the parent link, products, the sub menu comes down and the white background is showing, how ever, when I mouse over the sub menu the white background disappears and shows the image for the active class, I would just like the white background to stay the same, but only on the sub menu, I would still like the parent links to use the .active and a:hover class image. thanks, Phil

Comment: So the child-items should be the only items to get the white background? the parents should keep the blue one?

Comment: Edited my code above this should give you the desired result only thing is the active does not show with the menu item because the active image is white as well.

Comment: Great, thanks Marco, will amend now.  Any thoughts on the z-index problem?  Cheers, Phil

Comment: What seems to be the problem exactly with the z-index? As far as i see the menu folds over the image and everything seems to appear right?

Comment: It seems to be in front because of the height I have set for the sub menu list items, I have changed it from 30px to 60px, if you have a look now it will still go behind the roundabout. cheers, Phil

Comment: Ah i didn't realize that you where using a scripted slider. Set #top_nav ul { z-index:1010 } (anything above 1000 wil do) You need to set it above 1000 because most sliders have 1000 as a defaulted value because of the many images a slider can contain. Makes sense doesn't it?

Comment: It makes perfect sense now!!  I will get that amended also.  Thanks Marco, your information and help has been excellent. Cheers, Phil

Comment: Glad i could help, if you fixed it could you mark this as approved?

Comment: Fixed the sub-menu, looks great, just what they wanted, thank you so much Marco, will mark as approved.  Still can't work out the z-index though, I have tried 1010, 1020, 2000, nothing seems to work, so not sure if I need to amend something within the script?  Will keep at it though, thanks once again for all your help. Phil