# Vertical Menu CSS

Tags: html, css

```html
<nav class="nav">
<ul><li><a href="Mobile" phones="">Mobile Phones</a></li><ul><li><a href="Samsung">Samsung</a></li><ul><li><a href="dummy">dummy</a></li><ul></ul></ul><li><a href="Apple">Apple</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Huawei">Huawei</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="HTC">HTC</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="OnePlus">OnePlus</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="LG">LG</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="BlackBerry">BlackBerry</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Motorola">Motorola</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Google">Google</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Lenovo">Lenovo</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Infinix">Infinix</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Xiaomi">Xiaomi</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Oppo">Oppo</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="QMobiles">QMobiles</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Microsoft">Microsoft</a></li><ul></ul></ul><li><a href="Cameras">Cameras</a></li><ul><li><a href="Nikon" dslr="">Nikon DSLR</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Canon" dslr="">Canon DSLR</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Nikon" digital="">Nikon Digital</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Canon" digital="">Canon Digital</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Nikon" accessories="">Nikon Accessories</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Canon" accessories="">Canon Accessories</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Sigma" lenses="">Sigma Lenses</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Sony">Sony</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Panasonic">Panasonic</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Olympus">Olympus</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Samsung">Samsung</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Fujifilm">Fujifilm</a></li><ul></ul></ul><li><a href="Smart" watches="">Smart Watches</a></li><ul><li><a href="TAG" heuer="">TAG Heuer</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Apple" watch="">Apple Watch</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Motorola">Motorola</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Samsung">Samsung</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Pebble">Pebble</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="LG">LG</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Sony">Sony</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Huawei">Huawei</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="ASUS">ASUS</a></li><ul></ul></ul><li><a href="Laptops">Laptops</a></li><ul><li><a href="Apple">Apple</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Dell">Dell</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="HP">HP</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Lenovo">Lenovo</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Samsung">Samsung</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Accer">Accer</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Asus">Asus</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Toshiba">Toshiba</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Sony">Sony</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Xioami">Xioami</a></li><ul></ul></ul><li><a href="Washing" machines="">Washing Machines</a></li><ul><li><a href="Dawlance">Dawlance</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Haier">Haier</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Kenwood">Kenwood</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="LG">LG</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Samsung">Samsung</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Toshiba">Toshiba</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Hitachi">Hitachi</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Super" asia="">Super Asia</a></li><ul></ul></ul><li><a href="Television">Television</a></li><ul><li><a href="Samsung">Samsung</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Sony">Sony</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="LG">LG</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="EcoStar">EcoStar</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Haier">Haier</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Orient">Orient</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="TCL">TCL</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Changhong" ruba="">Changhong Ruba</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Sharp">Sharp</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Akira">Akira</a></li><ul></ul></ul><li><a href="Tablets">Tablets</a></li><ul><li><a href="Samsung">Samsung</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Huawei">Huawei</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Apple">Apple</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Dell">Dell</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Toshiba">Toshiba</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Accer">Accer</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Microsoft">Microsoft</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Lenovo">Lenovo</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Asus">Asus</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="HP" tablets="">HP Tablets</a></li><ul></ul></ul><li><a href="Refrigerator">Refrigerator</a></li><ul><li><a href="Dawlance">Dawlance</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Orient">Orient</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="PEL">PEL</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Waves">Waves</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Haier">Haier</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Sharp">Sharp</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Samsung">Samsung</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="LG">LG</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Changhong" ruba="">Changhong Ruba</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Electrolux">Electrolux</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Kenwood">Kenwood</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Hitachi">Hitachi</a></li><ul></ul></ul><li><a href="Split-ac">Split-ac</a></li><ul><li><a href="Dawlance">Dawlance</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Orient">Orient</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="PEL">PEL</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Waves">Waves</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Haier">Haier</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Sharp">Sharp</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Samsung">Samsung</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="LG">LG</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Changhong" ruba="">Changhong Ruba</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Electrolux">Electrolux</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Kenwood">Kenwood</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Hitachi">Hitachi</a></li><ul></ul><li><a href="Gree">Gree</a></li><ul></ul></ul></ul></nav>
```

Desired out put is wanted a  vertical menu showing root categories and on hover show its child category as a vertical menu bar

Like: 
Mobile Phones
Cameras
Smart Watches 
laptops
Washing Machines
Televisions
Tablets
Refrigerator
Split-ac

Comment: Have you tried to code anything up?

Comment: If you had the resources, you could use a kendo tree list

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a CSS only (vertical) drop-down menu?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141513/how-to-create-a-css-only-vertical-drop-down-menu)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using Bootstrap for this:
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav

Take a look at `.nav-stacked` in particular.