# Align sub list with the main list in html and css

Tags: html, css

I want to align sub list with the main list item.

```
<div class="ws__navbar" style="width:100%;">
  <div class="upbar" style="width:100%">
    <div class="ws__dropdown" style="width:15%">
      <div class="ws__dropbtn" id="faceimg" style="text-align:left; "><a href="#" style="color: black;">-</a></div>
      <ul class="ws__dropdown_content">
        <li type="none" class="has-sub"><a href="#">Products & Services</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li type="none"><a href="#" target="_blank">Wellhead Systems</a></li>
            <li type="none"><a href="#" target="_blank">Valves & Tree Systems</a></li>
          </ul>
          <li type="none" class='has-sub'><a href="https://www.inworld.com">world training</a>
          </li>
          <li type="none" class="has-sub"><a href="#">Functions</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li type="none"><a href="#" target="_blank">Standard Work1</a></li>
              <li type="none"><a href="#" target="_blank">Competency </a></li>
              <li type="none"><a href="#" target="_blank">Training</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li type="none" class="has-sub"><a href="#">Alerts</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li type="none"><a href="#" target="_blank">Operations Alerts</a></li>
              <li type="none"><a href="#" target="_blank">training Alerts</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.ws__navbar {
  overflow: visible;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.ws__dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: visible;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.ws__dropbtn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: orange;
}

.ws__dropdown:hover .ws__dropbtn {
  /*background-color: red;*/
  color: white;
}

.ws__dropdown_content {
  display: none;
  overflow: visible;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  width: 137px;
  z-index: 100;
  text-align: left;
}

.ws__dropdown_content a {
  background-color: black;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 15px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 33px;
  width: 120px;
}

.ws__dropdown_content a:hover {
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
}


/* show dropdown menu on hover */

.ws__dropdown:hover .ws__dropdown_content {
  display: block;
}

.upbar {
  float: left;
  overflow: visible;
}


/* Below :THE COLOR(Orange) OF TEXT IN THE LISTS BEFORE HOVER*/

ul li.has-sub a {
  color: #e65c00;
}


/* To change the color  of font on hover (orange to white)*/

ul. li.has-sub a font:hover {
  color: white;
}

ul li:hover>a {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background: red;
  border-color: transparent;
}


/* THE SUBMENUS */

ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: -9999px;
  opacity: 1;
  width: 140px;
}

ul li.has-sub {
  position: relative;
}

ul li.has-sub:hover>ul {
  display: block-inline;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -1px;
}


/* General link styling */

ul li a {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
}


/* Showing the submenu when the user is hovering the parent link */

ul li.has-sub:hover>ul {
  top: -32px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  left: 99%;
  right: 29%;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 1;
}

ul li.has-sub ul li :hover a {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: red;
}

li.has-sub {
  text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
}
```

This is how it is looking like. I dont want the space on left side which is appearing when submenu appers on hover the main list item. Also    the sub list is not appearing next to the main list item.
It shoud appear next to the main list item.

I am trying to make popup look like this:

```
 **|Link 1| |Link 2|______
          |-> Sublink 1|
          |-> Sublink 2|
          |____________|**
```

[image]

Comment: Your HTML is invalid, DIVS cannot be children of a `ul` only` li` are permitted.

Comment: Thanks @Paulie_D... I have removed the div...but nothing changed still its showing the  same result.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do

Comment: @EternalHour  I want simple sub list which will appear on hover. I have already done that. But as I have shared the image the space on the left hand side in main list it showing when sub list is appearing..I dont want that....how to solve this error

Comment: Well as Paulie said, to begin with your markup is invalid. Remove the divs from within the ul then update your question.

Comment: @EternalHour ...I have updated the code by removing the div..but still not getting the desired result

Comment: You're really far from where you need to be with the menu. I would suggest looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141513/how-to-create-a-css-only-vertical-drop-down-menu for some guidance.

Comment: @EternalHour..Thanks..the link you shared  was really helpful.. solved the issue